# Angular Material 10 range datepicker and moment.js Error: date.getFullYear is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, momentjs

Trying to implement Angular Material v10 datepicker with the rangePicker option with moment.js
But when I use moment in combination with the rangePicker it gives me this error.

`Error: date.getFullYear is not a function`

This error happens when I try to select the second date `matEndDate`

Modified Google Stackblitz example showing the error:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imb7gg?file=src/app/datepicker-moment-example.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range datepicker uses range strategy with wrong `DateAdapter`.

In order to fix it you should provide `MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY` token on **the same level** where you provided custom `DateAdapter`:

```
import {
  MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
  DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
...
providers: [
 { provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY, useClass: DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy},
 { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
 ....
```

It makes sure that `DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy` class will get MomentDateAdapter as a `DateAdapter` implementation instead of `NativeDateAdapter`

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imb7gg-e5v9nb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts)**

Comment: Works like a charm, I saw the NativeDateAdapter error but I just assumed MomentDateAdapter inherited or something.